# Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length error in wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have error that 
Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {0.*10^-16-1.000000000000000 I} {{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}} cannot be combined. >>

{0.*10^-16-1.000000000000000 I} {{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}

I can't solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you are trying to do. This will multiply the first item by every element in the second matrix

```
 {0.*10^-16-1.000000000000000 I}[[1]] {{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}
```

> {{0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. - 1. I, 
>     0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}}

```
 Chop@% // MatrixForm
```

[image]

That said this sort of error is often simply due to forgetting a semicolon terminating a statement causing results on separate lines to be multiplied when you had no intention of multiplying them.

Comment: agentp I did what you say above. But it gave me the error Part::partd: "Part specification (1.57009*10^-16+1.\ I)[[1]] is longer than depth of object." And I want to ask that Chop@% is equal MatrixForm[] code we know.Is it? Or it is another using method.

Comment: your new error is because you changed the brackets `{}`  to `()`